# System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip height or autosize

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2007, toolstrip, officedev

I'm using a series of ToolStrips in an Excel 2007 Actions Pane.  I'm programatically adding buttons to each ToolStrip and then adding each ToolStrip to the actions pane.  So far so good; my ToolStrips appear, with their associated ToolStripButtons.

The problem comes with displaying the entire contents of the ToolStrip. I have ToolStrip.AutoSize set to true (which is in fact the default).  The description for that Property is as follows:

> "Gets or sets a value indicating
>   whether the control is automatically
>   resized to display its entire
>   contents."

The problem is that even when it's set to true my ToolStrips show the width of the action pane but only one row high; for those ToolStrips that contain more buttons then can be displayed in that space the ToolStrip doesn't expand vertically to show the whole set of buttons, but instead shows the drop-down arrow on the right-side that allows the user to see the remaining buttons.

My question, then, is am I misinterpreting the usage of this property (or indeed, of this component)? Does the AutoSize only relate to horizontal space, for instance?  For whatever it's worth, I've also tried setting the height value to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set "LayoutStyle" property to "Flow" value. Then will items flowed to the next line.